# SQL union query in columns instead of rows

Tags: sql

I wrote a query for recording totals from columns from multiple tables however I could only get the data into rows, how could I get these into columns?

```
Select Sum(Price) AS [Totals]
From Sold

Union

  SELECT SUM(Total) as Down
    FROM
    (
     SELECT Cost as Total 
     FROM Sold
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Total as Total
     FROM Extras
     ) AS AllRowsFromT1andT2

UNION Select Sum(Valued) AS [Value]
From Sold;
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your looking for pivot functions

Comment: Please **always** indicate which database you are using. "SQL" - by itelf - just isn't sufficient to identify the syntax needed  as answres. (SQL implementation vary a lot between db vendors.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify it like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Price)  AS [Totals]
  , SUM(Valued) AS [Value]
  , SUM(Cost) + (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Extras) AS [Down]
FROM Sold
```

you can also prefix the column refrences which although not strictly necessary makes the logic more obvious.

```
SELECT
    SUM(Sold.Price)  AS [Totals]
  , SUM(Sold.Valued) AS [Value]
  , SUM(Sold.Cost) + (SELECT SUM(Extras.Total) FROM Extras) AS [Down]
FROM Sold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
(
Select Sum(Price) AS [Totals]
From Sold
) as Totals,
(
  SELECT SUM(Total) as Down
    FROM
    (
     SELECT Cost as Total 
     FROM Sold
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Total as Total
     FROM Extras
     ) AS AllRowsFromT1andT2
) as AllRowsFromT1andT2,
(
Select Sum(Valued) AS [Value]
From Sold
) as VALUE
```

SQL Server will work but depending on your database you may need to coerce the syntax. For example in Oracle you would need to `SELECT` <..all that..> `FROM DUAL`  Not sure about MySQL or others.